# Share data in files from a JS class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

Is there a way i can use a JS Class to populate an object with data from an API and then re-use that object from the class in different files so i have access to the same data object? For example:

I have a class that fetches and stores some data.

```
export default class Api {
    constructor() {

        // Config from DOM element
        this.config = JSON.parse( $( '.config' ).attr( 'data-config' ) );

        // The object we send back to the API
        this.payload = {
            'data': {
                'type': this.config.type,
                'paged': 1,
                'filters': []
            }
        };

        // API response comes in here
        this.response = {};
    }

    get() {
        const self = this;
        return new Promise( ( resolve ) => {
            $.ajax( {
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: this.config.apiUrl,
                data: JSON.stringify( this.payload ),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: ( response ) => {
                    self.response = response;
                    resolve();
                }
            } );
        } );
    }
}
```

file1.js:

```
import Api from '../helpers/api.js';

function fetchData () {
    Api.get().then( () => {
        // Do stuff after data fetched from class
        // Api.response has data now.
    } );
}
```

Now in file2.js i want to access the data stored in the `this.response` object that file1.js fetched.

file2.js

```
import Api from '../helpers/api.js';
console.log( Api.response ) // empty {}
```

I want the this.payload object in the Api Class to be updated from any file and then do a new call to the api.

I understand why it's empty because file2.js is using a new Class Api. But is there a way i can share this data without saving it in localStorage or the window object? Maybe i should not use a class for this but i'm kinda lost here. I sort of want the same thing that Vuex does but i'm not using Vue on this project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing data in class instance, but trying to read it from class static property

If you want to you classes, you should instantiate class to get access to instance properties you've initialized in constructor. And you should use [singleton](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-design-patterns-singleton/) pattern to get the same instance every time you call `new App()`

Or just export not a class, but a simple object with the same interface.

Comment: I've tried the last example in the singleton page you linked, i still get the same result. When i log the Api class in the two different files, i get 2 unique instances of the Api class instead of the same.

Comment: I've just posted the first link from duckduckgo just to explain what singleton is. Here's the code of class that instantiate singleton. I've checked it: https://dev.to/tomekbuszewski/singleton-in-javascript-1d5i =)

Comment: The main idea is to store first created instance in static class property and return that instance on next try to create new class instance